# Change the direction of ALL glyphicon-chevron to either up or down on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple accordions on the page and user can click on the glyphicon-chevron-up or glyphicon-chevron-down to expand or collapse them individually.
In order to do that this code is working for me:

```
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function () {
    $(this).children(".glyphicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-up glyphicon-chevron-down");
});
```

I also have two buttons on the page named "Collapse All" and "Expand All" that if clicked will collapse/expand ALL the accordions on the page and this is working OK too **except** one part that I need help with:
This code does NOT flip ALL the glyphicon-chevron icons to up or down. How can I add that functionality?

```
$("#showAllPanels").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".panel-collapse").collapse("show");
});

$("#hideAllPanels").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".panel-collapse").collapse("hide");
});
```

Comment: You already know how to toggle classes? `$(".glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-up").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down");`

Comment: @adeneo but then if BEFORE clicking the expand/collase ALL buttons, SOME of them are up and some of them are down, it will mess it up

Comment: Well yes, that's why you specifically add and remove classes instead of just toggling

Comment: @adeneo  oh ok, thanks. Didn't notice that part first.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `addClass()` and `removeClass()` methods like following.

```
$("#showAllPanels").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".panel-collapse").collapse("show");
    $(".glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-up").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down");
});

$("#hideAllPanels").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".panel-collapse").collapse("hide");
    $(".glyphicon-chevron-up").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
});
```